# multi channel buffer

Tags: design, buffer

What is necessary to drive two op amps (tl071 for instance) from one piezo guitar pickup, which of course is a very high impedance source? Result being, one very high impedance source creating two identical low impedance outputs that are isolated from each other. I have looked at a great number of buffer circuits, but none address the issue of using one source to drive two op amps. Thanks so much, for any help. Jon

Comment: Why do you need to drive two from the same piezo? Can't you just amplify it first?

Comment: The piezo output is high impedance and you can make the 2 opamps input impedance to match, so what is the problem? I´d just drive them directly and see what happens. You aren´t going to damage anything.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was pretty sure that I could do this, as I would be driving two identical circuits. There is an application that requires one piezo times 6 (one for each string) to drive two different circuits. They were not identical and so caused response problems as the two circuits interacted with each other. Hence the need for the buffer to provide isolation to the two existing circuits. Thanks again, I will be able to move forward and get this project done.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dual opamp and connect it as a voltage follower i.e. the - input is connected to the output, each output goes to the separate loads. The + inputs go to the output of the original opamp.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Since I actually need to provide circuits for all 6 strings of the guitar, I will probably go with a quad op amp times 3 to give me dual outputs for all 6 strings.

Comment: That should work. the LM324 and LM358 are the same. Be careful with the gain, you may lose the high end if it is to much.